# How to make node-sass-middleware not re-compile every time even if no changes?

Tags: node.js, express, sass, node-sass

From what I can ascertain the [node-sass-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-middleware) that I'm using to compile `.scss` files in Express re-compiles the `.css` files from my `.scss` files every time a request is served.

This isn't ideal for a production environment, I'd much prefer that it only re-compile the files if they've changed since the last compilation. I assume that this is possible by sniffing the target folders/files in some way but I was wondering if there's a straightforward way of achieving this that I'm unaware of. Maybe a flag for `node-sass` or something that I'm missing, although I can't find anything in the documentation.

It is possible that it isn't actually re-compiling each time to begin with, but I'm not sure how to test this.

Hope someone can help! Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

So it quickly occurred to me straight after submitting my question that I can just check the `last modified` metadata of the file to determine whether or not the file has been re-compiled. Whoops.

I did a test:

1. Launched the app and requested a page so that the `.css` file is compiled for the first time
2. Made a note of the `.css` file's `last modified` time
3. Requested the page again
4. Compared the current `last modified` time to the previous one and found no change
5. Made a change to the `.scss` file
6. Once again compared the `last modified` time and found that it's changed, in addition to the style changes being reflected on the page

As such I'm concluding that `node-sass-middleware` somehow detects that no changes have been made and doesn't unnecessarily re-compile the Sass, which is great to know. I guess that combined with its ability to cache CSS files in RAM, this is a very efficient solution out of the box.

Note: I've done some further testing and found that restarting the app will cause the Sass to be re-compiled even if no changes to the `.scss` file have been made and the existing `.css` file is perfectly valid. This suggests that there's slightly more to it than simply sniffing the folder/file contents.

Comment: Another observation: it seems to re-compile after a certain period of time (of which I'm not certain but it's at least five minutes) no matter what. This doesn't have any relation to the `maxAge` option because even when I set that to a few seconds it didn't re-compile after a minute or so.

Answer (score 0):

> re-compiles the `.css` files from my `.scss` files every time a request is served.

From [documentation](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware):

> **Optional configurations:**
>
> - `force` - `[true | false]`, false by default. Always re-compile.

I guess you can use your environment variables to prevent `.scss` re-compilation under production mode...